# Error when importing json array to Firebase and Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I used this code to export json array to cloud fire store

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./service-key.json");
const data = require("./state.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://functionstest-54bd9.firebaseio.com"
});
data && Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    const nestedContent = data[key];
    if (typeof nestedContent === "object") {
        Object.keys(nestedContent).forEach(docTitle => {
            admin.firestore()
                .collection(key)
                .doc(docTitle)
                .set(nestedContent[docTitle])
                .then((res) => {
                console.log("Document successfully written!");
            })
                .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

but when I run this I am getting error

```
Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.
    at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as isDocument] (/home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:86:15)
    at WriteBatch.set (/home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:264:14)
    at DocumentReference.set (/home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/reference.js:425:8)
    at Object.keys.forEach.docTitle (/home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/lib/migrate.js:17:18)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.keys.forEach.key (/home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/lib/migrate.js:13:36)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/lib/migrate.js:10:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
```

and my json file is

```
[
    {
        "countryId" : 1,
        "countryName" : "Any",
        "phoneCode" : null,
        "sortName" : null
    },
    {
        "countryId" : 2,
        "countryName" : "India",
        "phoneCode" : null,
        "sortName" : null
    }
]
```

**EDIT**

My input was a json array and the error was obvious and then I changed the json file like this

```
{"countries":[
    {
        "countryId" : 1,
        "countryName" : "Any",
        "phoneCode" : null,
        "sortName" : null
    },
    {
        "countryId" : 2,
        "countryName" : "India",
        "phoneCode" : null,
        "sortName" : null
    }
]
}
```

And when I tried again, I got this in the console

```
Error writing document:  { Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at /home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15 code: 7, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
Error writing document:  { Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at /home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15 code: 7, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
```

I have added a service account and added the json in the script. What is wrong in this?

Comment: That last json that you edited served me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set role when creating service account, Deleted the old one and created new service account with editor role and added the new json in the script. now it works